# how to migrate magento 1.9.2 site to a newly installed magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, magento1.9.2.4

I have a site in magento 1.9.2 and I am unable to access it's admin panel after spending 3 days, so I decided to make a new directory of magento and then migrate the old site to the new install.  So I installed a new copy of magento 1.9.2 and its working fine as I am able to access its admin panel and I can login via the admin panel in the newly installed magento directory.

Now I want to shift my full magento site to the newly installed magento. Can I migrate this site to another directory?? If yes then how can I migrate including database data, theme and extensions.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Was Konrad's answer helpful? If yes, think of crediting Konrad a little bit ... If not: tell him so and tell him why it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Doy you have access to database or code ?
You can reset admin password in easy way. Just run SQL like:

```
UPDATE admin_user SET `password` = md5('YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD'), is_active = 1 WHERE `username` = 'YOUR_ADMIN_USERNAME';
```

Then just login with your new password ;)

Comment: I am unable to access its admin panel login page

Comment: this script You have to run in Database directly.